# LibGDX font is blurry

Tags: fonts, libgdx

So i am creating font using this code

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/font.ttf"));
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.size =SCREEN_WIDTH/12;
      //  generator.scaleForPixelHeight((int)Math.ceil(SCREEN_WIDTH/12));
        parameter.genMipMaps = true;
      //  parameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear;
        parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
        parameter.borderStraight  =true;
        font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

but font end up being blurry no matter what texture filtering i am using 
i keep screen resolution low due to performance issues

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = 180;
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 320
```

is there a way to create nice and crisp font on this res, or this is as good as it gets ?

Comment: 180/12 is only 15 pixels tall, which is tiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your font is blurry because it's resolution is too small.

To solve this you could use the tool [Hiero](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/tools.html) (scroll to the bottom) which is mentioned in the [libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Bitmap-fonts) for creating bitmap fonts.

Open the tool and select the desired font from your system fonts (or from a file).

Then use the **size option** in this tool to set a big resolution for your font, according to your game (*size ~50 may be enough*).

Save the font files (.png and .fnt) and use it in your game. Now the font should not be blurry anymore.

Comment: I know this question is almost a year old but how do I use the png and fnt files for my game? Shouldn't it be a ttf file?

Comment: @DreamsInHD Sure, if the size of your font is big enough you could just use a .ttf file, check [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20044550/3871673).

If you want to use a bitmap font (which a fixed size, predefined in e.g. the tool Hiero) then check [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15689992/3871673).